# Workbox - How to ignore URIs matching a prefix

Tags: webpack, service-worker, webpack-dev-server, workbox

I'm using `webpack-dev-server` and have defined a a `devServer` field in `webpack.config.js`:

```
devServer: {
  host: "0.0.0.0",
  port: "80",
  proxy: {
    "/api": {
      target: "http://api:4000",
      pathRewrite: { "^/api": "" },
    },
  },
  historyApiFallback: true,
},
```

My `sw.js` file:

```
import { precacheAndRoute, createHandlerBoundToURL } from "workbox-precaching";
import { NavigationRoute, registerRoute } from "workbox-routing";

precacheAndRoute(self.__WB_MANIFEST);

const handler = createHandlerBoundToURL("/index.html");
const navigationRoute = new NavigationRoute(handler);
registerRoute(navigationRoute);
```

For some reason, when the server worker is installed, I'm not able to hit URIs matching `/api/*`. However, when I unregister the service worker, I *am* able to use the `/api` proxy.

How can I configure the service worker via `workbox` to not handle any URI starting with `/api/`?